# what is the difference between forward<T>(a) and (T&&)(a)

Tags: c++, c++11

```
template<typename T>  
void outer(T&& t) {inner(forward<T>(t));}  

template<typename T>  
void outer(T&& t) {inner((T&&)(t));}
```

what is the difference?

Answer (score 9):

There is no practical difference. `std::forward<T>(v)` is specified as `static_cast<T&&>(v)`.

`§20.2.3 [forward]`

```
template <class T> T&& forward(typename remove_reference<T>::type& t) noexcept;
template <class T> T&& forward(typename remove_reference<T>::type&& t) noexcept;
```

> 2 *Returns:* `static_cast<T&&>(t)`.

A C-style cast goes through most C++-style casts to determine the first working one. One of them is `static_cast`, which also is the first one that works in this case.

`§5.4 [expr.cast] p4`

> The conversions performed by
>
> - a `const_cast` (5.2.11),
> - a `static_cast` (5.2.9),
> - a `static_cast` followed by a `const_cast`,
> - a `reinterpret_cast` (5.2.10), or
> - a `reinterpret_cast` followed by a `const_cast`,
>
> can be performed using the cast notation of explicit type conversion. [...] If a conversion can be interpreted in more than one of the ways listed above, the interpretation that appears first in the list is used, even if a cast resulting from that interpretation is ill-formed.

I'd advise to stick with `std::forward`, though. The intent is clear from the name and and people will know what it does much more likely than knowing what a weird `static_cast<T&&>` (or even `(T&&)`) does.

Answer (score 1):

There is no effective difference. Here is how VC++ defines forward<> for rvalue references:

```
template<class _Ty> inline
    _Ty&& forward(typename remove_reference<_Ty>::type&& _Arg) _NOEXCEPT
    { // forward anything
        static_assert(!is_lvalue_reference<_Ty>::value, "bad forward call");
        return (static_cast<_Ty&&>(_Arg));
    }
```

Comment: The _standard_ defines it! This is how VC++ implements it.

Comment: How one implementation (which is known to implement stuff... not totally conforming) implements a feature doesn't tell much. :/

Comment: @Lightness: This is also a function template *definition*. :P

Comment: @Xeo: That was the very definition of touché!