# std::forward vs static_cast on variadic args

Tags: c++, forward, variadic-functions, static-cast

i dont't fully get what does "&&" after variadic parameter do. are following functions generally the same, or there is a difference in some cases?

```
template <typename... Args>
void function1(Args&&... args)
{
    some_other_function(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <typename... Args>
void function2(Args&&... args)
{
    some_other_function(static_cast<Args&&>(args)...);
}
```

i've tested a lot of possibilities and all give the same effect for both functions.

Comment: See a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward "CPP Reference - std::forward") on the return value. Also, look for "universal reference".

Comment: You should go with `std::forward` because nobody will see what `static_cast<Ty &&>` does at first glance.
Technically `std::forward` is nothing more than `static_cast<Ty &&>` (See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13668172/2176127) for more information).